# HighCharts: Uppercase for labels won't work on FireFox

Tags: jquery, highcharts

When setting Uppercase for labels:

```
xAxis:{
    labels: {
        style: {
            textTransform: "uppercase"
        }
    }
}
```

It work on any browser but FireFox (v.23.0.1 and v.24.0).

See example:
http://jsfiddle.net/udhSa/

Is there any workaround or do I need to html Format it and add class with uppercase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.useHTML) parameter and problem will disappear

```
labels: {
            useHTML:true,
            style: {
                textTransform: "uppercase",
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/udhSa/1/

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [for highchart below 7th version]

```
 ...
legend: {
    textTransform: "uppercase"
 },
...
```